# How to access Vuex store within component props to set defaults

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I'm new to JS and Vue (using Vue3, Vuex4, router4). I have a view that displays data for the 3 most recent months (with options to show other months, so they need to be able to change).

When this view is refreshed, those months that were passed as props are gone, and you have to go back a page and click the link again.

I moved them to the store to have global access:

```js
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    isLoading: false,
    recentMonths: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setIsLoading(state, status) {
      state.isLoading = status
    },
  },
  actions: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    setRecentMonths({ commit }, payload) {
      const tfs = new Array()
      for (let m of Array(payload.numToGet).keys()) {
        let curDate = new Date()
        let prvDate = new Date(curDate.getFullYear(),curDate.getMonth() - m, curDate.getMonth())
        tfs.push(prvDate.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'long', year: 'numeric'}))
      }
      this.state.recentMonths = tfs.reverse()
    }
  },
  modules: {},
})
```

Below is fine - sets the default as expected if the props are missing, so when my users refresh or bookmark their page, it will load something.

```js
export default {
  props: {
    timeframes: {
      type: Array,
      default() { return ['April 2021', 'May 2021', 'June 2021'] }
    }
  },
```

But, I need to be able to figure out what the months are, rather than hard-coding for each view that requires the months. Cannot figure out how to get something like this to work:

```js
export default {
  props: {
    timeframes: {
      type: Array,
      default() { return this.$store.state.recentMonths }
    }
  },
```

I realize I have no access to **this** here, just trying to show what the intention is. Perhaps I'm putting everything in the wrong place. Any ideas?

Comment: you could initialize the value in an hook like `created` that would have the store available, and your prop would have the default value before it uses it.

Comment: Why not just add a `computed` that returns `this.timeframes || this.$store.state.recentMonths`?

Comment: @Rosie Your last example *does* give you access to `this.$store` in `default()`, so the default *should* be initialized to `this.$store.state.recentMonths`.

Comment: @tony19 ty, but with vue3 I get this error: Props default value factory functions no longer have access to `this`

Comment: @MattU gosh - because I was too hung up on trying to get default to work I guess haha. if you post as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a computed property that returns `timeframes` or the value from the store:

**Component script**

```js
export default {
  // other stuff
  computed: {
    currentTimeframes: function() {
      return this.timeframes || this.$store.state.recentMonths
    }
  }
}
```